# setting BorderLayout and having paintComponent() called

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, paintcomponent

My problem : I have a `RoundedPanel` class that extends `JPanel` and overrides `paintComponent()` method in order to draw rounded corners around the panel. I created a `MyPanel` class that extends `RoundedPanel`.

When I put a panel on `MyPanel` using `FlowLayout` layout, the rounded border appears.
In order for the components on panel to be resized so that they fill the maximum space, I replaced the `FlowLayout` by a `Borderlayout`. But then , the `paintComponent()` method is never called and the rounded border doesn't appear anymore.

Does anyone knows how to create a rounded panel whose components are stretched to fill the space when the window is resized? Could someone explain me why the `paintComponent()` method is not called when using Borderlayout ?

Thanks in advance.

The code :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Demo extends JFrame {

    public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 540;
    public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 540;
    private static MyPanel myPanel;

    private Demo() {
        super();
        myPanel = new MyPanel();
        getContentPane().add(myPanel);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }
}

class MyPanel extends RoundedPanel {

    private JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();

    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        rootPanel = buildRootPanel();
        rootPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        rootPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        add(rootPanel);

        // When uncommented, the Textfield is correctly resized to fit all available space , but the rounder border doesnt appear
        //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //add(rootPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JPanel buildRootPanel() {
        rootPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        rootPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return rootPanel;
    }
}

class RoundedPanel extends JPanel {

    protected int strokeSize = 1;//Stroke size. it is recommended to set it to 1 for better view
    private Color strokeColor = Color.BLACK;
    protected Color shadowColor = Color.black;//Color of shadow
    protected boolean shady = true;//  Sets if it drops shadow
    protected boolean highQuality = true;// Sets if it has an High Quality view
    protected Dimension arcs = new Dimension(20, 20);// Double values for Horizontal and Vertical radius of corner arcs
    protected int shadowGap = 5;// Distance between shadow border and opaque panel border
    protected int shadowOffset = 4; // The offset of shadow.
    protected int shadowAlpha = 150;// The transparency value of shadow. ( 0 - 255)

    public RoundedPanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++ in paintComponent");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int shadowGap = this.shadowGap;
        Color shadowColorA = new Color(shadowColor.getRed(), shadowColor.getGreen(), shadowColor.getBlue(), shadowAlpha);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Sets antialiasing if HQ.
        if (highQuality) {
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        //Draws shadow borders if any.
        if (shady) {
            graphics.setColor(shadowColorA);
            graphics.fillRoundRect(
                shadowOffset,// X position
                shadowOffset,// Y position
                width - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // width
                height - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // height
                arcs.width, arcs.height);// arc Dimension
        } else {
            shadowGap = 1;
        }

        //Draws the rounded opaque panel with borders.
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap, height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);
        //graphics.setColor(getForeground());
        graphics.setColor(strokeColor);

        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap, height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);

        //Sets strokes to default, is better.
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the field occupies all the space of the panel. If child covers all the parent and parent isn't visible no need to call the paintComponent() so it's not called.
Try to add empty border to the content.

Comment: I tried to add an empty border but the rounded border still does not appear.

Comment: @user980340 setting an emptyborder worksforme, be sure to make it big enough, f.i. 10 in every direction

Comment: In the MyPanel class , I added the following line :
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

     and now it works : the rounded border appears and the components are resized automatically. Thanks great to StanislavL and  kleopatra !